# must be non-null but is marked as nullable only when using lambdas

Tags: findbugs

I found a curious behaviour in sonarqube and I don't know if it is a bug, or I am just not understanding the mechanics of lambdas well enough.

In our codebase we have some code like:

```
@Nullable
private Runnable nulltest(@Nullable String myNullableString) {
    if(myNullableString == null) {
        return null;
    }


    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("This string is not null: " + myNullableString);
        }
    };
}
```

and this code is fine, sonarqube does not have an issue with it.
But if I change the code to using lambdas like so:

```
 @Nullable
 private Runnable nulltest(@Nullable String myNullableString) {
    if(myNullableString == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return () -> System.out.println("This string is not null: " + myNullableString);
}
```

Then I get the following error:
findbugs:NP_PARAMETER_MUST_BE_NONNULL_BUT_MARKED_AS_NULLABLE
myNullableString must be non-null but is marked as nullable

So I don't understandwhy is it one time a problem and the other time not. Is this a bug or is there a real difference between the lambda version and the anonymous class version of this method?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. But FindBugs is [no longer maintained](https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1487/), so that's not surprising. Try [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/), maybe they have fixed it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Jensen, it seems to be indeed a bug, already reported to spotbugs

https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/552